# Implicitly used property

Tags: annotations, resharper

I have a POCO object, which is being serialized using reflection.

```
public class Session
{
    public int Version { get; private set; }
}
```

I have tried using various combinations of [UsedImplicitly] on the class and the property, but no matter what, it seems as if resharper insist on claiming 'Auto-implemented property accessor is never used' and on suggesting that: "Property 'Version' can be made private". Neither which is true.

I can accept having some amounts of attribute decorations, but polluting the source code with comments for the purpose of making resharper happy is not.

How can I get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in 8.0 and 8.1, and the following works:

```
public class Session
{
    [UsedImplicitly]
    public int Version { get; private set; }
}
```

The private setter is marked as in use.

Comment: I found the problem, turns out that the checkmark on JetBrains.Annotations, under ReSharper|Options|Code Annotations had gone missing. With the checkmark, it works as expected. It would have been nice with an inspection warning about this.